# Calling a List inside JSON two objects using retrofit in Android Studio

Tags: java, json, android-studio, retrofit

I am trying to get the list inside of this JSON list, but i have no idea if my model is right when it comes to calling two objects before the list strings, i am getting a null for the calling of the list.

This is my JSON format

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "match": [
        {
            "away_id": 2139,
            "time": "FT",
            "status": "FINISHED",
            "location": "Audi Field",
            "added": "2020-09-27 22:45:11",
            "league_id": 0,
            "away_name": "New England Rev.",
            "ht_score": "0 - 0",
            "league_name": "",
```

And also this my retrofit call

```
       Call<ListScore.Data> call = api.getScore("WxdGLZuYSNjotTDv","jI8rjjZFjYcCttVq186M8AK0o3oSW2og");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListScore.Data>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListScore.Data> call, Response<ListScore.Data> response) {

            ListScore.Data dataList = response.body();
            List<ListScore.Data.Matches> soccerlist = dataList.getMatch();
            score = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
                score.add(new ListScore.Data.Matches(
                        soccerlist.get(i).getStatus()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getScore()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getAwayName()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getAdded()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getHomeName()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getLocation()));
            };
```

and this is my Logcat error.

```
 09-27 21:53:58.690 3477-3477/com.example.football E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.football, PID: 3477
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.football.Score$1.onResponse(Score.java:94)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

This is my model class

```
public class ListScore {

@SerializedName("success")
public boolean success;

@SerializedName("data")
public Data data;

    public static class Data{

        @SerializedName("match")
        private List<Matches> match = null;

            public static class Matches {
                @SerializedName("status")
                private String status;

                @SerializedName("score")
                private String score;

                @SerializedName("away_name")
                private String awayName;

                @SerializedName("added")
                private String added;

                @SerializedName("home_name")
                private String homeName;

                @SerializedName("location")
                private String location;


                public Matches(String status, String score, String awayName, String added, String homeName,
                               String location) {
                    super();
                    this.status = status;
                    this.score = score;
                    this.awayName = awayName;
                    this.added = added;
                    this.homeName = homeName;
                    this.location = location;
                }


                public String getStatus() {
                    return status;
                }

                public void setStatus(String status) {
                    this.status = status;
                }

                public String getScore() {
                    return score;
                }

                public void setScore(String score) {
                    this.score = score;
                }

                public String getAwayName() {
                    return awayName;
                }

                public void setAwayName(String awayName) {
                    this.awayName = awayName;
                }

                public String getAdded() {
                    return added;
                }

                public void setAdded(String added) {
                    this.added = added;
                }

                public String getHomeName() {
                    return homeName;
                }

                public void setHomeName(String homeName) {
                    this.homeName = homeName;
                }

                public String getLocation() {
                    return location;
                }

                public void setLocation(String location) {
                    this.location = location;
                }

            }

            public List<Matches> getMatch () {
            return match;
        }

            public void setMatch (List < Matches > match) {
            this.match = match;
        }
    }

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}

public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```

I hope someone can help on this so i can learn a lot.

Comment: Share your model classes as well.

Comment: i already did thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check soccerlist above for loop and set Breakpoint inside for debugging:

```
if (soccerlist != null && soccerlist.size >= 2){
    // your code below
} else {
    // case list null or size is smaller than 2
}
```

I thought your list may be null or size is smaller than 2 then it throw NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, i just have to change my declaration in my retrofit call

```
    Call<ListScore> call = api.getScore("WxdGLZuYSNjotTDv","jI8rjjZFjYcCttVq186M8AK0o3oSW2og");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListScore>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListScore> call, Response<ListScore> response) {

            ListScore dataList = response.body();
            List<ListScore.Data.Matches> soccerlist = dataList.getData().getMatch();
            score = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0; i<soccerlist.size(); i++) {
                score.add(new ListScore.Data.Matches(
                        soccerlist.get(i).getStatus()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getScore()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getAwayName()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getAdded()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getHomeName()
                        , soccerlist.get(i).getLocation()));
            };
```